# jquery unobtrusive how to override validation method

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to validate a number that not is required but the native method don't allow this.

There is a way to override the native method or I have to add a custom method?

**Edit**

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Foo must be a number." id="Foo" name="Foo" type="text" value="">
```

*Note: this is generated by asp.net mvc*

Comment: could you please share your HTML ans JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work for me

```
  $(function() {
        $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
            return !value || Globalize.parseFloat(value).toString() != "NaN";
        }
  }
```